# using external library in angular2+webpack app

Tags: angular, webpack-2

I am new to angular 2 and writing a new client-side angular2 cli generated application (with webpack2). My component needs to use this splunkjs object from this external library https://github.com/splunk/splunk-sdk-javascript .
I want to be able to get to this splunkjs object but I am unable to do so within the angular2 app's component :

```
var http = new splunkjs.JQueryHttp();
```

In a standalone javascript, I am able to get to it using:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="splunk.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    function test() {
 var http = new splunkjs.JQueryHttp();
 console.log(' http is ' + JSON.stringify(http));
}
    </script> 
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="test()">Test</button>
</body>
```

What would be the steps to do above in my angular component instead?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding jquery and splunk-sdk as dependencies in package.json and then adding paths to their dist scripts in .angular-cli.json in the "scripts" section. Here is a good reference https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-cli-adding-third-party-libraries